# Lost connection to MySQL server during query on Google Cloud MySQL server

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am aware that this question has been asked multiple times, but I haven't found a question that pertains to the same issue I am dealing with. I have a MySQL database hosted on Google Cloud SQL. I am running a python script out of a Google Cloud VM to connect to the database to run queries. Everything used to run fine, but now I am getting the following error on my initial connection to the server.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 327, in __init__
    self.connect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 597, in connect
    self._get_server_information()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 966, in _get_server_information
    packet = self._read_packet()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 656, in _read_packet
    packet_header = self._read_bytes(4)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 702, in _read_bytes
    CR.CR_SERVER_LOST, "Lost connection to MySQL server during query")
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

And here is the code I am using to connect to the server

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
    user='xxxxxx',
    password='xxxxxx',
    database='foobar',
    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
    max_allowed_packet=16777216,
    connect_timeout=100)
```

Initially, my connection code did not have the *max_allowed_packet* and *connect_timeout*, and it was working fine. After some research into my issue, these seemed to resolve others' issues, but it hasn't resolved mine.

Answer (score 0):

You must add wait_timeout and start by 10000 and then see.

The other will not help, but i added iy you have another timeout that will not be catch by connection and wait timeout

- **interactive_timeout** Number of seconds the server waits for activity on an interactive connection before closing it
- **wait_timeout** Number of seconds the server waits for activity on a connection before closing it

It seems

use a mysql command right after the connection

```
SET session wait_timeout=300;
```

Comment: neither of these parameters are used by the pymysql class though, so how do I add them? and can you clarify what you mean by "the other will not help..."?

Comment: use the mysql command first command after connection. Syntanx see answer